# Error getting Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h'

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

When i run my flutter app i get this error

## Lexical or Preprocessor Issue (Xcode): 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found

## /Users/macbookpro/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dev/sqflite-2.3.0/ios/Classes/SqfliteImport.h:10:8

i also get this error for image_picker_ios and path_provider_foundation

Flutter clean
Flutter pub get
pod install,

i also cleared the pod cache, till got nothing.